# joomla-3: неправильное формирование ссылок в модулях типа Articles - Category

Tags: joomla

На сайте имеется несколько модулей типа Блог категории. Модули на заданных страницах выводят списки анонсов к статьям и ссылки "Читать дальше". Но эти ссылки сформированы с неверными адресами и сами статьи не открываются. Если в заголовке анонса стоит вывод категории, то ссылка на него также формируется неправильно. Где искать ошибку? Joomla 3.4.5, Denwer, PHP 5.3.13, MySQL 5.5.25.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо бы посмотреть на примеры ссылок которые формирует модуль, строение ссылок может очень помочь для обнаружении дефекта. Модули самостоятельно формируют ссылкы на конкретную статью, рабочая ссылка должна приблизительно выглядеть в формате  http://domain.ru/content_id-content_alias (если конечно данные статьи не привязанны к меню)
Если статьи находятся в одной категории, необходимо проверить есть ли в Меню Менеджере ссылка которая привязана к данной категории, если такого меню нет, необходимо создать и для меню выбрать "Тип меню" категория-блог.